# PowerMockito mock gets cleared after calling real method

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermock, localdate

I'm experiencing a weird behaviour with PowerMockito static method mocking.

[image]

**Note:** `2020-08-27` is the real system time at the time of executing the test.

In the above code example as you can see I have mocked all the implementations of `LocalDate.now()` method and all the implementations of `LocalDateTime.now()` method. And I want the real implementation of `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime)` method at the same time.

All the mocks are working correctly until I call the `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime)` method.

When I call the `LocalDateTime.now()` after calling `LocalDateTime.of(LocalDate, LocalTime)` I get the real system time not the mock value for the 1st time. But if I `LocalDateTime.now()` again then I again get the mocked time.

A debug screenshot is attached above with the mock results. This is the code I'm using.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*"})
// This is needed due to a compatibility issue of Power Mock with JDK 9 (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/864#issuecomment-447001997)
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        String dateString = "2020-08-24T09:00:00Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDate.class);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDate.now()).thenReturn(localDate);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDate.now(Mockito.any(ZoneId.class))).thenReturn(localDate);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDate.now(Mockito.any(Clock.class))).thenReturn(localDate);

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(LocalDateTime.class);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDateTime.of(Mockito.any(LocalDate.class), Mockito.any(LocalTime.class))).thenCallRealMethod();
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDateTime.now()).thenReturn(localDateTime);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDateTime.now(Mockito.any(ZoneId.class))).thenReturn(localDateTime);
        PowerMockito.when(LocalDateTime.now(Mockito.any(Clock.class))).thenReturn(localDateTime);

        LocalDate now1 = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime of = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.of(10, 30));
        LocalDate now2 = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate now3 = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

I have spent several hours looking out for the root cause but unfortunately no luck yet. Can someone please tell me what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bug with `PowerMockito.mockStatic` itself. I posted the same at https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/1066 also. But I didn't get any response yet. Anyway, I was able to find a solution for my use case with `PowerMockito.stub` method. The following code piece works as expected without any issue.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"com.sun.org.apache.xerces.*", "javax.xml.*", "org.xml.*", "org.w3c.dom.*"})
// This is needed due to a compatibility issue of Power Mock with JDK 9 (https://github.com/powermock/powermock/issues/864#issuecomment-447001997)
public class MainTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

        String dateString = "2020-08-24T09:00:00Z";
        Instant instant = Instant.parse(dateString);
        LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, ZoneId.of("UTC"));

        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDate.class, "now")).toReturn(localDate);
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDate.class, "now", ZoneId.class)).toReturn(localDate);
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDate.class, "now", Clock.class)).toReturn(localDate);

        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDateTime.class, "now")).toReturn(localDateTime);
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDateTime.class, "now", ZoneId.class)).toReturn(localDateTime);
        PowerMockito.stub(PowerMockito.method(LocalDateTime.class, "now", Clock.class)).toReturn(localDateTime);

        LocalDate now1 = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDateTime of = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, LocalTime.of(10, 30));
        LocalDate now2 = LocalDate.now();
        LocalDate now3 = LocalDate.now();
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

The difference between 2 approaches are with `PowerMockito.mockStatic` I mock the whole class and then define the behaviour of each method with `PowerMockito.when`. The methods which haven't been defined with `PowerMockito.when` will return null or do nothing if invoked. But with `PowerMockito.stub` I don't mock the whole class. I define the mocked behaviour only for a selected set of methods with `PowerMockito.stub` and other methods will call the real methods if invoked.